# At what pressure will ambient atmospheric air liquify?

Tags: physical-chemistry

At what pressure will ambient atmospheric air liquify? (Ambient Earth atmosphere at say five foot above sea level. From any specific point on Earth, since it would vary from point to point due to differing compositions at different locations of course.)

I realize that would never happen naturally on earth, anywhere above sea level, of course. Rather, I am asking about artificially pressurized ambient air that is stored under pressure.

(Sorry, not sure if this should be categorized as a chemistry or physics question since it's really both at once.)

Comment: Nitrogen , oxygen ,argon ?

Comment: Read up on phase diagrams and supercritical fluids to answer that question.

Answer (score 4):

Air cannot be liquified at temperature naturally occuring on Earth.

More exactly, oxygen cannot be liquified above -118.6°C, nitrogen above -146.9°C.

Things are little more complicated as air is a mixture, but you can get the picture.

At extreme pressures like tens or hundreds gigapascals, air would solidify.